# How to use AVPacket as local variable(or said temporary variable)

Tags: c++, audio, memory, ffmpeg

my program receive a aac audio stream from net,and use ffmpeg to decode the stream,so I must pack the stream data to a AVPacket struct,I use a local variable to do this, the code like below:

```
bool OnRecvAACStream(const char * audioDataPtr,int audioDataSize,int64_t tBeg,int64_t tDura)
{
    AVPacket pkt_tmp;   // local varible
    av_init_packet(&pkt_tmp);
    pkt_tmp.data = audioDataPtr;
    pkt_tmp.size = audioDataSize;
    pkt_tmp.pts = tBeg;
    pkt_tmp.duration = tDura;
    
    if (avcodec_send_packet(m_codec_ctx, &pkt_tmp) < 0)
    {
        assert(false);
        return false;
    }
    while (avcodec_receive_frame(m_codec_ctx, m_dec_frame) == 0)
    {
       // read out dec audio data
       ...
    }
    
    retur true;
}
```

I just use av_init_packet() to init the local varible, av_packet_unref() and av_packet_free() are not called,so is it valid? is there any memory leak problem?

Answer (score 0):

`av_init_packet` doesn't allocate anything. Just sets default values for AVPacket structure and doesn't touch data and size field. You should keep track of `.data` part, when anything allocated, it has to be freed before overwritten.

According to the code above, you'll probably wanna use `av_frame_free` and/or `av_frame_unref`, before you done with the current frame and next frame kicks in.